# error while using replace in an update statement in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting error while using replace in an update statement in sql server 2008.
the statement I'm trying to run is :

```
    update table US14-HSS-SQUARE_AISC14-HSS-SQUARE set Designation = replace(Designation,'HSSSQUARE','HSS') where Designation like 'HSSSQUARE%';
```

want to change 'HSSSQUARE' to 'HSS' in each row of the column 'Designation'. e.g. 
'HSSSQUARE16X16X5/8'  to 'HSS16X16X5/8'.

is there any other syntax in sql server 2008?

Comment: Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
> update table US14-HSS-SQUARE_AISC14-HSS-SQUARE set Designation = replace(Designation,'HSSSQUARE','HSS') where Designation 
like 'HSSSQUARE%';
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = table ]

Comment: GarethD just beat me to it... you don't need the `table` after `update`

Comment: that was the error message in the sql server management studio..

Comment: Glad to hear it, and note the answer was in the error message `Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = table` ("token line offset" being the position of the first character of the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `table` in the update statement, and you also need to wrap your table name in square brackets if you are going to put illegal characters in it.

```
UPDATE  [US14-HSS-SQUARE_AISC14-HSS-SQUARE] 
SET     Designation = REPLACE(Designation,'HSSSQUARE','HSS') 
WHERE   Designation like 'HSSSQUARE%'
```